# Powering up second LM386N results in screaming squeal

Tags: audio, feedback, lm386, guitar-pedal

So I'm definitely a newcomer in the audio electronics realm but I've been really digging into circuits and experimenting with sounds. I've been focusing alot of time working through examples that use pairs of LM386N ICs for a distorted audio signal. In the circuit I've posted here I'm getting a loud squeal whenever I powerup the second LM386 in the chain. Could someone tell me what I have wrong that's causing this to happen and what I need to do to fix it? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Insert 1 ohm and 1000uF capacitor, in TWO places, in the  VDD pin of each IC. The oscillation likely has the VDD rail as feedback path. So filter that VDD. Perhaps increase the resistor to 3.3 ohm or 10 ohm.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 thanks for the comment, what would you recommend for improving the FET bias?

Comment: You have Vgs at 9V/2 which is in cutoff mode. Reduce  Vgs so the drain Vd is well above 0V in linear range by moving R1 ground end to drain for self bias.

Comment: D2 is redundant. C2 cuts off low frequency

Comment: Any stray coupling of output of 2nd stage near input of 1st stage with lots of gain can cause positive feedback (squeal)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 so, as I’m just learning, could you give me an example of where I have stray couplings and what makes it that way? Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Current in nearby  wires is  inductive and voltage is  capacitive coupling in high impedance  inputs. IF  loading with 1k to 10K reduces the crosstalk, then you know there was crosstalk.  Got any pictures of layout?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I've added a photo of the breadboard layout. Input is at the top left corner (purple wire), output is lower right (dark blue wire). Bottom most is the rail for power (in4001, 100uF combo)

Comment: I don’t see a short path on Q1-D to V+ with a decoupling cap. And orange V+ leads from cap to IC is too long, delete diode and use the rails with cap close to both IC’s use twist pair with ground for in and out.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 what would be a good cap size on Q1-D to V+? 100p?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anything else is wrong, but always bypass your power pins.  And I mean always, on everything.  In this case it means a 100nF cap between pins 6 and 4 of each chip, placed as close to the chip and with the shortest leads that are practical.

You should also have some bulk bypass -- I'd go with a 100uF electrolytic cap from +V to ground, just about anywhere on the board.